# Does polymorph any object strip your magic items from you?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, polymorph

I thought I was finally done with some of this after someone answered that melded gear that is not functioning has no weight. But another player in the game has raised another concern/point.

The issue with with [polymorph any object](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/polymorph-any-object). At first I thought they were talking about the target which does not allow you to target magic items. Instead it was

> A non-magical object cannot be made into a magic item with this spell. Magic items aren't affected by this spell.

So when you are not duplicating the effects of one of the others, this should happen. Does this line mean all magical gear on a creature falls around them? So armor, weapons, rings, ... would just fall to the ground instead of melding like with regular polymorph effects because of this line? This assumes that the new form you are being given does not have the correct magic item slots.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means you can't target a magic item with the spell.  If you target a creature, its gear merges with it per the polymorph school description.

Comment: Its already mentioned in the targeting part, but have the extra line about magical items not being affected?

Comment: Yeah, they're reiterating it.

Answer (score 4):

### The gear merges with the creature.

From: **Polymorph**, PHB pg. 265:

> The target’s gear melds into the new form. The creature can’t activate, use, wield, or otherwise benefit from any of its equipment.